# Javascript replace all doesn't work in safari on macOS/iOS

Tags: javascript, str-replace

I got below error in safari on macOS/iOS

Consider I need to replace a placeholder with actual price

```
const formattedPrice = '$1,100.00';
str.replace( /\|\|TOTAL_REPAYMENT_CHARGES\|\|/g, formattedPrice);
```

the result of above would be `,100.00`

but if i use below one, it works

```
const formattedPrice = '$1,100.00';
str.replace( '||TOTAL_REPAYMENT_CHARGES||', formattedPrice)
```

the result would be `$1,100.00`

can someone explain what happened? thanks

Answer (score 3):

When the first parameter of `.replace` is a regular expression, and the second parameter of `.replace` is a string, JS will parse the second parameter [according to some rules](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_string_as_a_parameter), allowing for the concise replacement with the full match or a capture group. For example, `$&` indicates to replace with the full match:

```js
console.log('foo'.replace(/o/g, 'a$&'));
```

Above, each match is replaced with `a`, followed by the full match, and both full matches are `o`, so both matches are replaced with `ao`.

In your code, the `$1` is being interpreted as "replace this part with the first capture group". But your code doesn't have any capture groups, so instead of matches being replaced with `'$1,100.00'`, they get replaced with `',100.00'`.

To indicate a literal `$`, use *two* `$`s, like this:

```
const formattedPrice = '$$1,100.00';
//                       ^
str.replace( /\|\|TOTAL_REPAYMENT_CHARGES\|\|/g, formattedPrice);
```

Comment: awesome explanation. is it safari only? at least chrome doesn't have this problem

Comment: Oh really? That's quite interesting, I'll fire up my VM to open Safari and see. If their behaviors are not exactly the same, I'd be almost certain this is a bug, I'll look into it

Comment: I can't replicate the problem in Safari 11.0 on High Sierra, nor on Chrome. Does the problem occur in this fiddle for you? https://jsfiddle.net/jr97ps5y/ What version of Safari are you using, on what mac system?

Comment: my macOS is 10.13.6, and safari is 13.0.4
let me create a repo